# How to change the background colour on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I have Windows 8, and the background is very white. Since I am dyslexic, I find this hard.

One of the things that I could do was change the white background in the Personalisation options to a colour like yellow or pink to help. This has been removed in Windows 8.

I found and followed the registry hack for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Microsoft\ControlPanel\Colors\`, but Windows for some reason keeps resetting it.

Is there a permanent solution for this, preferably with a GUI?

Here is an example picture in Outlook.

[image: White background]

Comment: I don't know any GUI. We all submitted feedback since Developer Preview, but ignored the feedback :( You must use the registry or wait until someone create a GUI for you.

Comment: Damn was afraid of that

Comment: My Windows 8 has no white backgrounds.  Can you provide an example of where you're seeing this? It may need to be set in a couple places to achieve what you want.

Comment: You mean that the registry hack gives the desired output but the problem is that it needs to be done after every restart ?
If that is the case, there are ways to make the registry hack permanent. I would be better if you can provide some screenshots of desired and problematic GUI.

Comment: add picture to questions as an example

Comment: also if you could point me to some of the places in an answer it might help others...

Answer (score -1):

There is free utility for this. [Windows 8 background color changer](http://changer.petrlz.cz/en/)

Comment: could u elaborate ur answer?

Comment: Besides that, the site you pointed seems like it was put up in a second, by someone with limited English skills. After reading the author and your name it seems as if you were self-promoting your product. As Vignesh said, please elaborate.